# Non-abelian solvable group of order $p^2q$ that including no subgroup of order $pq$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory, solvable-groups

I am working on a  non-abelian  solvable group of order $p^2q$ that  including no subgroup of order $pq $. My problem is this:

Does this group have a normal sylow $p$-subgroup?

In the case that $p>q$, yeah I know it does.

For the case $p<q$, I really have no idea. I tried to show this case won't happen, but I couldn't.

How can I use the solvability of $G$?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: A small comment: neither the hypothesis of solubility nor of non-abelianess are necessary. Non-abelian follows from the fact that the group has no subgroup of order $pq$, while solubility follows from the order being $pq^2$. The first is quite easy, the second only a little bit harder.

Comment: Yeah.  I wrote all the hypothesis that I knew.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $G$ is solvable but not abelian, we know it must have an abelian normal subgroup that is not trivial. Because we are also assuming $G$ has no subgroup of order $pq$ at all, then this normal abelian subgroup must be of order $p$, of order $p^2$, or of order $q$.

If it is $P$ of order $p$, and we let $Q=\langle x\rangle$ be a subgroup of order $q$, then the normality of $P$ tells us that $PQ=QP$, so $PQ$ is a subgroup. What is its order?

Similarly, if it has a normal subgroup $Q$ of order $q$, and we let $y$ be an element of order $p$, then letting $P=\langle y\rangle$ we have $QP=PQ$, hence $PQ$ is a subgroup. What is its order?

Comment: Thank you so much. Today I had worked on it and i figured out this solotion just you said. Actually I was thinking in wrong way. yeah, $PQ$ has order $pq$ , a conradiction.

Comment: @raharaha: You can only “accept” one answer. It looks like yesterday you switched, then switched again. If all answers are satisfactory, then just pick whichever answer you think was the most useful to you and “accept” that one (the arrow under the vote counting).

Answer (score 1):

The case $p<q$ can occur. The alternating group $A_4$ is non abelian, solvable, has no subgroup of order $6$, and does not have a normal subgroup of order $2$ ($p=2,q=3$)

Comment: In fact $G = A_4$ is the only group where this occurs. That is, if $G$ is nonabelian of order $p^2q$ with $p < q$ primes and $G$ has no subgroup of order $pq$, then $G \cong A_4$.

Comment: The question asked about a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup, not a normal subgroup of order $p$.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Thank you so much. I wasn't looking for a normal subgroup of order p.